# Should I create a separate table for this use case?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, rdbms

I need to onboard some of my merchants on a third party platform, for which I need to send merchant details along with a request ref no.(rrn) (unique for every onboarding request). After onboarding, whether the merchant actually got onboarded or not will be done by a seperate verify api, which will require me to send request ref no.
The question is whether I should add a new column in my already existing merchants table or should I create a separate table for mapping merchant_id with request rrn, given that only 5% of merchants will be onboarded on this third-party?

Comment: I suggest to put it in separate table, right now you only have the ref_no but in the future add additional column for onboarding_comments and others.

Comment: onboarding status in the same table and other info if needed in another table, ideally another table will be useful in 1 to many scenarios

Answer (score 1):

As long as the merchants table is small (less than 1 million), you can just add a column to the table and index it

Comment: MySQL can a handle indexed table  in de billions Count just fine with indexes

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you store this information in a separate table.  You have described a simple scenario, but the actual scenario might be more complicated:

- There is a timelag between starting the on-boarding and it being successful.
- Perhaps the onboarding is not successful.
- If a merchant can be "onboarded", they can be "offboarded".
- And then onboarded again.

In other words, if you are managing the process, you should keep track of each of the possibilities.

If you are *not* managing the process and the merchant simply tells you that they are onboarded, then storing the information as a flag is fine.